# R interleave two data frames with same column names

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data tables:

- `before` represents a data table in its "raw" state (prior to any cleaning operations).
- `after` represents a data table after various cleaning and manipulation.

They have mostly matching column names.

Is it possible to construct a third data frame where columns with matching names are placed adjacent to one another and the names possibly modified (`name.before`, `name.after`) and all excess columns are placed at the end?

For example:

`before` data frame:

```
data.table::data.table(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(1,2,3), c = c(1,2,3))

   a b c
1: 1 1 1
2: 2 2 2
3: 3 3 3
```

`after` data frame:

```
data.table::data.table(a = c("a","b","c"), c = c("a","b","c"), d = c(1,2,3))

   a c d
1: a a 1
2: b b 2
3: c c 3
```

The desired output would be:

```
   a.before a.after c.before c.after d
1:        1       a        1       a 1
2:        2       b        2       b 2
3:        3       c        3       c 3
```

The purpose of this would be for easy comparison of identical columns to verify that column outputs are appropriate after various functions have been applied to the data.table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to `cbind` and use `setcolorder` on the `order`ed column names concatenate and then use `make.unique` if the intention is to identify the before/after on the duplicate column names

```
library(data.table)
out <- setcolorder(cbind(dt1, dt2), order(c(names(dt1), names(dt2))))[]
setnames(out, make.unique(names(out)))[]
out[, setdiff(names(dt1), names(dt2)) := NULL][]
#   a.before a.after c.before c.after d
#1:        1       a        1       a 1
#2:        2       b        2       b 2
#3:        3       c        3       c 3
```

---

If we need to specifically use `before/after`

```
out <- setcolorder(cbind(dt1, dt2), order(c(names(dt1), names(dt2))))[]    
out[, setdiff(names(dt1), names(dt2)) := NULL][]
i1 <- duplicated(names(out), fromLast = TRUE)
i2 <- duplicated(names(out))
names(out)[i1] <- paste0(names(out)[i1], ".before")
names(out)[i2] <- paste0(names(out)[i2], ".after")   

out
#   a.before a.after c.before c.after d
#1:        1       a        1       a 1
#2:        2       b        2       b 2
#3:        3       c        3       c 3
```

Comment: Both are wrong as b column is not on the right. "all excess columns are placed at the end"

Comment: @polkas thanks, I missed that part.  Updated the solutions

Answer (score 2):

base R playground:

```r
cols_after <- colnames(after)

cols_before <- colnames(before)

inter <- intersect(cols_after, cols_before)

in_after <- cols_after %in% inter

n_after <- paste0(cols_after[in_after], ".after")

colnames(after)[in_after] <- n_after

in_before <- cols_before %in% inter

n_before <- paste0(cols_before[in_before], ".before")

colnames(before)[in_before] <- n_before

# some merge procedure merge_df or simple cbind
merge_df <- cbind(after, before)

merge_df_names <- merge_df[, c(as.vector(t(data.frame(n_before ,n_after))), 
colnames(merge_df)[!(colnames(merge_df) %in% c(n_before, n_after))])]

# if merge_df is data.table we need with = FALSE
# merge_df[, c(as.vector(t(data.frame(n_before ,n_after))), colnames(merge_df)[!(colnames(merge_df) %in% c(n_before, n_after))]), with = FALSE]

merge_df_names

# to remove b column if needed
# merge_df_names <- merge_df_names[, setdiff(colnames(merge_df_names), "b")]
# if merge_df is data.table we need with = FALSE
```

Comment: According to OP's post, the 'b' should not in the expected output.  May be you need to use `setdiff`

Comment: So still both solution then are wrong. However both of us know that it should be on the right.

Comment: May be it is a typo from the OP.  Not sure.  It would be better to clarify from OP

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**  Unaffected columns (`b`, `d`) are displayed last.

This tidyverse approach accepts data.table objects and also returns a data.table object:

```
library(tidyverse)

cols_to_rename <- intersect(colnames(before), colnames(after))

rename_cols <- function(data, suffix) 
  data %>% rename_with(~paste0(., suffix), all_of(cols_to_rename))

bind_cols(rename_cols(before, ".before"), rename_cols(after, ".after")) %>%
  select(starts_with(paste0(cols_to_rename, ".")), everything())

   a.before a.after c.before c.after b d
1:        1       a        1       a 1 1
2:        2       b        2       b 2 2
3:        3       c        3       c 3 3
```